# Creating Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, prime-numbers

By relative prime factor theorem
 $$R = (Zm,+,.)$$
where R is the ring structure
the input is $e_0 = 0$ and $e_1=1$
output is $$S_0 = { k : \gcd(m,k)>1 }$$
$$S_1 = { k : \gcd(m,k) = 1}$$

Now consider an example ie Z15
For Z mod 15 
$$S_0 = {0,3,5,6,9,10,12}$$
$$S_1 = {1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14}$$

what will be the polynomial which defines S1?

Comment: What does it mean for a polynomial $P$ to define $S_1$?